# Can't connect ST-Link with APM32F003 through OpenOCD

Tags: c, embedded, cortex-m, openocd

I'm using CLion and try to debug my APM32F003 base project with ST-Link.

I cannot determine what the problem is with ST-Link.

I'm using Geehy's OpenOCD build with APM32F003 config files.

My project cfg code is

```
source [find interface/stlink.cfg]

transport select hla_swd

set WORKAREASIZE 0x2000
set CPUTAPID 0x0bc11477
source [find target/apm32f003.cfg]
reset_config srst_only
```

Also, I have tried apm32f0xx.cfg too, the outputs are different, but both have `openocd.exe: unknown option -- interpreter=mi2` error.

The apm32f003.cfg is:

```
   openocd-geehy\bin\openocd.exe: unknown option -- interpreter=mi2
    ght differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
    srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_deassert_srst
    
    
    Process finished with exit code 0
    Info : clock speed 100 kHz
    Info : STLINK V2J37S7 (API v2) VID:PID 0483:3748
    Info : Target voltage: 3.270417
    Info : [apm32f003.cpu] Cortex-M0+ r0p1 processor detected
    Info : [apm32f003.cpu] target has 4 breakpoints, 2 watchpoints
    Info : starting gdb server for apm32f003.cpu on 3333
    Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
    [apm32f003.cpu] halted due to breakpoint, current mode: Thread
    xPSR: 0xf1000000 pc: 0xfffffffe msp: 0xfffffffc
    GDB Server stopped, exit code 1
```

And for apm32f0xx.cfg:

```
openocd-geehy\bin\openocd.exe -c "tcl_port disabled" -c "gdb_port 3333" -c "telnet_port 4444" -s \openocd-geehy\share\openocd\scripts -f geehy_apm32f00x.cfg -c "program Production.elf" -c "init;reset run;" -c "echo (((READY)))"
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.12.0-rc2+dev-00019-g9d925776b-dirty (2022-11-22-17:13)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results mi
ght differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_deassert_srst

Info : clock speed 1000 kHz
Info : STLINK V2J37S7 (API v2) VID:PID 0483:3748
Info : Target voltage: 3.269266
Info : [apm32f0xx.cpu] Cortex-M0+ r0p1 processor detected
Info : [apm32f0xx.cpu] target has 4 breakpoints, 2 watchpoints
Error: read_memory: read at 0x40015804 with width=32 and count=1 failed
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.12.0-rc2+dev-00019-g9d925776b-dirty (2022-11-22-17:13)
Error executing event examine-end on target apm32f0xx.cpu:
\openocd-geehy\share\openocd\scripts/mem_helper.
tcl:7: Error: read_memory: failed to read memory
in procedure 'program'
in procedure 'apm32f0xx_default_examine_end' called at file "\openocd-geehy\share\openocd\scripts/target/apm32f0xx.cfg", line 92

in procedure 'mmw' called at file "\openocd-geeh
y\share\openocd\scripts/target/apm32f0xx.cfg", line 73
in procedure 'mrw' called at file "\openocd-geeh
y\share\openocd\scripts/mem_helper.tcl", line 32
at file "\openocd-geehy\share\openocd\scripts/me
m_helper.tcl", line 7
Info : starting gdb server for apm32f0xx.cpu on 3333
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
[apm32f0xx.cpu] halted due to breakpoint, current mode: Thread
xPSR: 0xf1000000 pc: 0xfffffffe msp: 0xfffffffc
Info : Unable to match requested speed 1000 kHz, using 950 kHz

Process finished with exit code 0
Info : Unable to match requested speed 1000 kHz, using 950 kHz
Error: read_memory: read at 0x40015804 with width=32 and count=1 failed
For bug reports, read
Error executing event examine-end on target apm32f0xx.cpu:
\openocd-geehy\share\openocd\scripts/mem_helper.
tcl:7: Error: read_memory: failed to read memory
in procedure 'program'
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
in procedure 'ocd_process_reset'
in procedure 'ocd_process_reset_inner' called at file "embedded:startup.tcl", li
ne 1193\openocd-geehy\bin\openocd.exe: unknown option -- interpreter=mi2

in procedure 'apm32f0xx_default_examine_end' called at file "openocd-geehy\share\openocd\scripts/target/apm32f0xx.cfg", line 92

in procedure 'mmw' called at file "\openocd-geeh
y\share\openocd\scripts/target/apm32f0xx.cfg", line 73
in procedure 'mrw' called at file "\openocd-geeh
y\share\openocd\scripts/mem_helper.tcl", line 32
at file "openocd-geehy\share\openocd\scripts/me
m_helper.tcl", line 7
GDB Server stopped, exit code 1
```

Comment: It seems that connecting an ST-Link to non ST parts is not straight forward or guaranteed to work.  Discussed at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/250664/can-i-use-st-link-programmer-for-non-st-chips

Comment: ... Given the low cost of a Geehy-LINK, and the high value of your time, that might be a simpler solution.

Comment: It is not so easy to get Geehy-LINK fast in 404 world =)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was at my side (Im was a bit confused by another SO Answer and also set openocd as GDB debuger for IDE. That causes this ungooglable issues.

For now it works fine. Geehy's OpenOCD + ST-Link + APM32F003.

Comment: This is not an answer since you have simply told us it now works, not what you did to make it work.  If you do not wish to provide an answer and no longer require an answer, delete the question.  It has no merit as a community resource unless it allows others to resolve the same or similar issues.